# Ignore HTML tags in QC REST API output

Tags: html, rest, api, alm, hp-quality-center

Using HP ALM REST API, we get the Memo fields embedded with HTML tags such as `<html>`, `<span>`, `<body>`, etc. Is there a way to suppress the same using any options?

Using the earlier OTA API, we had the option to use `tdconnection.IgnoreHtmlFormat=True`, which used to suppress these tags, but using REST API, I am unable to find an equivalent one. Any suggestions or should I build  a parser myself after reading the output?

Comment: Please double check that your question displays as intended.  Did your HTML tags get swallowed by markdown?

Comment: why do you want to ignore html tags? is it showing on user interface? or you want to completely remove html tags and show non html content?

Comment: I need only the text without the html tags.. as i mentioned in my post, i am aware of writing a parser, but want to know if i can get a clean output from REST API itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally don't know of a switch like that.

Alternatively you might try this:
[How to Parse Only Text from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507353/how-to-parse-only-text-from-html)

On paper this seems quite nice.

This requires an extra step though. After getting the request you'ld have to run it through the proposed library to get the get the flat text. Shouldn't be more than a line of code I think.

Downside is there might be some stuff going south because you dump any formatting stored as HTML. Usually that isn't much though. Depends of the project and the people off course.

Comment: yes this is better using a one line code, but i had hoped that i would have some built in options from HP.

Comment: Would be nice indeed. Certainly if I hear they already have got the functionality. It only isn't exposed via the REST. Don't know on which version of HP QC you are now, but note that the latest has got a huge expansion over the 11.52 for example - or so the tale goes.